# Should you block port 80 (for UDP packets only) when hosting a web server?

Tags: http, udp, ddos

Should you block port 80 (for incomming  UDP packets only) when hosting a web server?
Could this defend against UDP Floods when this rule is applied upstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should probably be blocking everything except what you intend to receive anyway. Blocking them upstream will save your web server from having to send ICMP unreachable messages.